# De identification of production data

Tags: ruby, regex, string

I am using the production data of certain users to be used for testing and development purposes. So basically I want to convert data looking like

`Mohan` to `Mxxxx`

or `Sujeet` to `Sxxxxx`

What I have used :

```
2.0.0-p594 :053 > a = "Mohini".split("")
 => ["M", "o", "h", "i", "n", "i"] 
2.0.0-p594 :054 > x = a.shift
 => "M" 
2.0.0-p594 :055 > x+a.join().gsub(/\w/, "x")
 => "Mxxxxx"
```

seems to work fine for me, but is there a more elegant way of doing this, instead of splitting and joining.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the below regex and replace the matched character by `x`

```
(?<=.).
```

Dot `.` is a special meta character in regex which matches any character. Positive Lookbehind asserts that the match must be preceded by the characters which are matched by the pattern inside the lookbehind. In our case, the above regex matches all the characters which are preceded by a character. So it matches all the characters except the first one, because it there isn't a character exists before the first character.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/vN3sH3/43)

```
> "Sujeet".gsub(/(?<=.)./, "x")
=> "Sxxxxx"
> "Mohan".gsub(/(?<=.)./, "x")
=> "Mxxxx"
```

Some other methods to change `Mohan Kumar Singh` to `Mxxxx Kxxxx Sxxxx`

```
> "Mohan Kumar Singh".gsub(/[a-z]/, "x")
=> "Mxxxx Kxxxx Sxxxx"
> "Mohan Kumar Singh".gsub(/[^A-Z\s]/, "x")
=> "Mxxxx Kxxxx Sxxxx"
> "Mohan Kumar Singh".gsub(/\B./, "x")
=> "Mxxxx Kxxxx Sxxxx"
```

To change `Mohan Kumar Singh` to `Mxxxx xxxxx xxxxx`

```
> "Mohan Kumar Singh".gsub(/(?<=.)\S/, "x")
=> "Mxxxx xxxxx xxxxx"
```

`\S` matches a non-space character.

Comment: I have got the solution, appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

Not very elegant, but much simpler:

```
name = "Mohan"
name[0, 1] + "x"*(name.size-1)
#=> "Mxxxx"
```

If the name contains fullname, it can still be done this way, however it wont be that pretty:

```
name = "Sujeet Singh"
name.split.collect {|n| n[0, 1] + "x"*(n.size-1)}.join(' ')
#=> "Sxxxxx Sxxxx"
```

or

```
name = "Mohan Kumar Singh"
name.split.collect {|n| n[0, 1] + "x"*(n.size-1)}.join(' ')
=> "Mxxxx Kxxxx Sxxxx"
```

Comment: hmm thats one way of doing it, thanks ! I needed it to work for strings like "Sujeet Singh" to "Sxxxxx xxxxx" as well. See if you can make it work this way

Comment: aelor, that changes the question. Don't change it here. Edit your question!